# Trouble using ssh and Avahi

Tags: networking, lubuntu, ssh, avahi

**Solved:** make sure that libnss-mdns is installed!

I'm having trouble using SSH'ing from my netbook to my desktop using a .local hostname. Every so often, I have to reset the router I use, which resets the addresses it give out to my devices, so a while ago I set up Avahi to get around this*. The /etc/avahi/services/ssh.service file is the standard one copied from the documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<!-- See avahi.service(5) for more information about this configuration file -->
<service-group>
    <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
       <service>
            <type>_ssh._tcp</type>
            <port>22</port>
       </service>
 </service-group>
```

This used to work fine, but now for some reason when I try to ssh from my netbook to my desktop, I get the following error message (note I changed my pc's hostname in this output):

```
user@netbook>> ssh pc.local -vvv
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pc.local: Name or service not known
```

I can ssh from my netbook to my PC when I put in the IP address manually, and when I've set up /etc/hosts correctly (so the daemon on my PC is working fine), it only stops working when I try to use the .local address. SSH'ing in the other direction (PC->netbook) works fine, even when using a .local hostname. Avahi also appears to be working fine:

```
user@netbook>> avahi-browse -a -t+  
+  wlan0 IPv6 netbook                                  SSH Remote Terminal       local
+  wlan0 IPv6 netbook [<MAC address>]       Workstation                       local
+  wlan0 IPv6 netbook                                  Remote Disk Management local
+  wlan0 IPv4 netbook                                  SSH Remote Terminal       local
+  wlan0 IPv4 netbook [<MAC address>]       Workstation                       local
+  wlan0 IPv4 netbook                                  Remote Disk Management local
+  wlan0 IPv4 pc                                          SSH Remote Terminal       local
+  wlan0 IPv4 pc [<MAC address>]               Workstation                       local
+  wlan0 IPv4 pc                                          Remote Disk Management local
+  wlan0 IPv6 pc                                          SSH Remote Terminal       local
+  wlan0 IPv6 pc [<MAC address>]               Workstation                      local
+  wlan0 IPv6 pc                                          Remote Disk Management local
```

The netbook is running Lubuntu 13.10; note that I did change to Lubuntu recently, and I only recall seeing this error with Lubuntu and not with plain Ubuntu. My desktop is running Ubuntu 13.10.

Any help would be appreciated!

*I am aware that can set up my router to permanently give set addresses to both devices, and I will do that if I can't resolve this issue, but I'd prefer to try and fix this rather than work around it.

ETA: Pinging the PC from the netbook with the .local hostname doesn't work (unknown host) .

Edit 2: Contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: I haven't used DHCP nor Avahi for a while now, but can't you simply `ssh user@hostname:/folder`?

Comment: Did ping test pass `ping pc.local`?

Comment: @Alex: Ideally that's what I'd like to do, but as I pointed out in the post every so often I have to reset the router, which resets the addresses it gives out, which mean's I'd be changing /etc/hosts files regularly, which is why I set up Avahi.

Comment: @Sneetsher: Just tried it, and it doesn't: "ping: unknown host pc.local."

Comment: Running  `strace ssh user@foo` will also show that ssh contacts avahi-daemon with the request to resolve `foo`, which times out... In my case changed in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`: From "`hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`" to "`hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal`". Not sure why avahi daemon is supposed to NOT ask DNS servers, it may have to do something with the incompatibility between multicast DNS and DNS both on the LAN (see also: [.local TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) ... having  `.local` is bad practice anyway)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, `*.local` are not resolved.

So on **Client machine (Notebook)**

1. Install `avahi-dnsconfd`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-dnsconfd avahi-discover avahi-utils
   ```

   `avahi-dnsconfd` listens to the publishing and passes them to `resolvconf`.
2. Install `libnss-mdns` ***(This library was missing, Installing it fixed the problem in this case)***

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libnss-mdns
   ```

   > nss-mdns is a plugin for the GNU Name Service Switch (NSS) functionality
   >   of the GNU C Library (glibc) providing host name resolution via Multicast
   >   DNS (using Zeroconf, aka Apple Bonjour / Apple Rendezvous ), effectively
   >   allowing name resolution by common Unix/Linux programs in the ad-hoc mDNS
   >   domain .local
3. Check `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

   ```
   hosts:     files wins mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
   ```

   It should have `mdns4_minimal` or `mdns4` before `[NOTFOUND=return]` and before `dns` if you have a DNS server that  configured resolve `*.local`.

   Remove `wins` if you are not using winbind/samba to resolve 
   Windows share hostnames.
4. Reboot

---

## Debuging hints:

- **Client machine (Notebook)**

  1. Check `avahi-dnsconfd` service status

     ```
     $ service avahi-dnsconfd status
     avahi-dnsconfd start/running, process 1548
     ```
  2. Run `avahi-discover`, Your desktop should be listed in IPv4→local→Workstation

     Example in screenshot `mx5` is my PC where `salah-Aspire-5738` is an other machine.

     [image]
  3. See if Avahi can resolve host names

     ```
     avahi-resolve -4 --name yourdesktop.local
     ```
  4. Ping test

     ```
     $ ping salah-Aspire-5738.local
     PING salah-Aspire-5738.local (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
     64 bytes from salah-Aspire-5738.local (192.168.1.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.69 ms
     ```
- **Server machine (Desktop)**, In case `avahi-discover` in Client machine did not list Server entry.

  1. Confirm that `avahi-daemon` is installed

     ```
     sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-dnsconfd avahi-discover avahi-utils
     ```

     `avahi-daemon` provide services publishing.
  2. Check its service status

     ```
     $ service avahi-daemon status
     avahi-daemon start/running, process 1517
     ```
  3. By default `avahi` publish `_workstation._tcp` service. check using `avahi-discover` locally, if not listed try enabling it in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` (remove `#`)

     ```
     publish-workstation=yes
     ```

     Then restart daemon:

     ```
     sudo service avahi-daemon restart
     ```

     Check again.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. `avahi-discover` and `avahi-dnsconfd` were not installed on my netbook or PC, so I installed them on both. I also edited `/etc/nsswitch` to look like the sample you provided (previously the only entries were files and dns) but both `ping` and `avahi` still give the same error. Any more advice?

Comment: Arrgh, this is extremely perplexing.

Comment: Removing `wins` did not help. `avahi-dnsconf` _is_ running on the netbook (though I had to use `sudo service avahi-dnsconfd` to list it, otherwise `service` would respond with unknown job). `avahi-discover` (when run on my netbook) _does_ list the desktop (and correctly), both under the Workstation heading and the ssh heading. Yet I still cannot ping or ssh into the pc using .local hostnames. I checked the daemon on the desktop anyway, and `avahi-daemon` _is_ running. Any ideas? (btw, thanks for all your advice, I appreciate it)

Comment: @thatSeniorGuy, `avahi-resolve -4 --name yourdesktop.local` ?

Comment: That responds with the correct IP address.

Comment: oh God finally :), so problem just in DNS resolving on the Notebook side. @thatSeniorGuy Could you add contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to the question.

Comment: :P Added (P.S. I probably won't be able to get at my netbook tomorrow, bit busy).

Comment: Any more advice?

Comment: try reinstall the mdns module for nss `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss-mdns` ?

Comment: Wasn't installed. Installed it, and it worked!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much for your help! Maybe add that to your post so others can see it a bit easier?

Comment: @Sneetsher It is not working for me with systemd in 16.04? Can you confirm?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, I will try in vbox, but i expect it to work. Could you follow debugging hints and report if you can't get same output.

Comment: @Sneetsher Now it works after I restart the service with systemd way (using `systemctl`) But doesn't show all remotes regardless `avahi-dnsconfd` installed or not.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, Have you check  missing  remote machine have `avahi-daemon` installed and configured correctly as above *"Server machine (Desktop)"*.

Comment: @Sneetsher Yes. I did. However, The remote machine doesn't have to be Linux/Ubuntu. Anything that announces its services on your local network by way of Zeroconf/Bonjour should work. Like [SSHelper](http://arachnoid.com/android/SSHelper/) for android which is working fine btw. Actually it's other Ubuntu machine (`avahi-daemon` installed and running) that is creating problem. Anyway I will recheck and let you know.

Comment: @user.dz Thank you for this! My problem was right at the end with "not publishing the workstation". I was frustrated and confused because I could see the hostname show up from the client side when running avahi-discover, but SSH wouldn't find or connect to it. Looks like I needed to publish a `workstation` service!