# Ubuntu 18.04 stopps resolving .local domains, but not always

Tags: networking, mdns

I've been trying to format a Drobo to use with linux. While I was doing this ubuntu suddenly stopped resolving .local domains, breaking big parts of my configuration. I could fix this by just using the ips, but I'd really like to learn what the problem is, since I actually did not really change anything on the system configuration, especially nothing network related, most if it is rather mint.

Possibly unrelated: the only thing I tried was a .deb archive for drobo-utils, which i downloaded from their sourceforge repo. Being an abandoned project that install failed without an error. I then installed drobo-utils via apt-get install, which was an outdated version, so I uninstalled via apt-get remove and dowloaded the plain version which I ran manually. 
All my attempts to format the drobo failed likely to the drobo not supporting linux (don't by this overpriced crap, I regret it).

So while i was running all sorts of commands (fdisk, parted, mke2fs, as I said nothing remotely network related) I noticed my homebridge installation reporting it could not resolve a .local domain. This however is not consistent, sometimes restarting homebridge helps and it can resolve .local again, then it stops again.

I am completely clueless about what to check. Everything I find when looking for not being able to resolve .local seems either outdated or completely unrelated to my problem, I I'd like to understand what kind of commands I am pasting into my terminal, so I also did not change any configuration yet.

I'm hoping to find somebody helpful who could try figure it out with me step by step.

Comment: "most if it is rather mint." Please indicate which version of Mint.

Comment: a few ports allowed in UFW. This version of mint. Installed mosquitto and homebridge.

Comment: @0xDE4DBEEF I'm not familiar with Homebridge (not sure how it works if the similar to ZeroTier bridging). Could you check https://askubuntu.com/a/460449/26246 . Could you add more info while troubleshooting. If Homebridge is like ZeroTier, you need to set the active interface for Avahi, otherwise it may publish the local ip instead of bridged one, so you will not able to connect even if it get resolved.